# Mobilock app starts before BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast... How is it possible?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

There is a kiosk app called Mobilock. This app starts way faster (Almost 5 seconds before) than my own app which starts with BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

My own app has the highest priority which is max value of integer. So this is not about the priority.

These guys have found a way to start their application 5 second sooner than BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

Has anyone got an idea about what they are doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh my god! I've luckily found it. :)

[This Page Says](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot.html) : Apps must register their components with the system before they can run during Direct Boot mode or access device encrypted storage. Apps register with the system by marking components as encryption aware. To mark your component as encryption aware, set the android:directBootAware attribute to true in your manifest.

Encryption aware components can register to receive a ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast message from the system when the device has been restarted. At this point device encrypted storage is available, and your component can execute tasks that need to be run during Direct Boot mode, such as triggering a scheduled alarm.

You just need to put

> android:directBootAware="true"

So the code in manifest is;

```
<receiver
  android:directBootAware="true" >
  ...
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: This solution is the cure for the others who suffer from delay in BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

Comment: Great stuff Serhat!

Answer (score 3):

Listen also to `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` and `android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

It seems to be device-dependant, which broadcast is sent first.

Comment: Thank you but this is not the problem in my situation. I think these guys have found a sooner trigger than boot broadcasts. I need to find this.