# This apps boot completed is fast

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

If you use this source, it will be called as soon as "boot completed" is booted. How is this possible? It takes more than 20 seconds for my smartphone(galaxy s5) to be used as it is.

the original app is here
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=qlocker.gesture&hl=ko

**manifest**

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <service android:name="qlocker.common.LockerService" android:process=":locker" />
        <receiver android:name="qlocker.common.LockerService$LockerBootReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**lockerService.java**

```java
     public final class LockerBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
          public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                  Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, LockerService.class);
                  intent2.putExtra("extra.LOCK_ON_BOOT", true);
                context.startService(intent2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094426/4978534).

1- Add

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

to your intent filter.

2- Add android:directBootAware="true" to your intent filter so your manifest should look like this:

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".LockerBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:directBootAware="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

2- Replace your code

```
 public final class LockerBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()) || "android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
              Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, LockerService.class);
              intent2.putExtra("extra.LOCK_ON_BOOT", true);
            context.startService(intent2);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer has been a great help. Android n and later models will run normally. However, it is sad that previous versions do not work because it is not a direct boot.

Comment: Please don't use `android:priority` more than [SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY). Max value allowed is `999`