# How to start an Android app while booting

Tags: java, android, boot

I want to start my app while the device is booting and not after boot completed, 
i already tested the intent intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED but i want to start my app before that,

```
        <receiver android:name=".Activity.StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Like you see, i made my app to priority 1000 but the problem still here, 
the purpose of my question is to start my app before the Bluetooth try to connect.

Have you ideas of how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is "Encryption aware" it can receive ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts.

Add `android:directBootAware="true"` to your manifest file.

Credit:  [@Serhat Türkman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091317/mobilock-app-starts-before-boot-completed-broadcast-how-is-it-possible)